# Execute coroutines in pararell and wait for all to finish

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a viewmodel that does different requests to the API, I'm currently calling my API like this

```
        val call1 = repo.getCall1()
        val call2 = repo.getCall2()
        val call3 = repo.getCall3()
        val call4 = repo.getCall4()
        val call5 = repo.getCall5()
        val call6 = repo.getCall6()
```

the problem with this approach is that I need to wait for each one to finish to start the other , after I do this calls to the repo (which are all suspend functions) I notify the livedatas, but this takes a little long (4 - 5 seconds) and I would like to do all the calls at the same time and catch them all at once before notifying my livedata

I'm looking for something like this

```
myCoroutineScope.launch {

            call1 = repo.getCall1()
            call2 = repo.getCall2()
            call3 = repo.getCall3()
            call4 = repo.getCall4()
            call5 = repo.getCall5()
            call6 = repo.getCall6()
    }.awaitForAllToFinish()
```

I would like to use **async - await** instead of jobs

Comment: In Kotlin, async-await _are_ jobs of the same kind as those you `launch`. The only difference is that you don't expect a result value from a `launch`ed job. Do you even use the return value? If not, then you don't need `async` and should use `coroutineScope { launch(task1); launch(task2) ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the results of all the calls are of the same type, you can use `listOf` and `awaitAll` to do it:

```
val results = listOf(
        async { repo.getCall1() }
        async { repo.getCall2() }
        async { repo.getCall3() }
        async { repo.getCall4() }
        async { repo.getCall5() }
        async { repo.getCall6() }
    ).awaitAll()
```

If they aren't, I guess you'd want to keep variables for each. Note that unlike your original code, this runs them in parallel.

```
val call1 = async { repo.getCall1() }
val call2 = //...

val result1 = call1.await()
val result2 = call2.await()
// ...

// use the results
```

Or to do it like you suggested in your first comment, maybe like this (didn't check it). But once again, not practical if the result types aren't all the same.

```
val call1 = async { repo.getCall1() }
val call2 = //...

val jobs = listOf(call1, call2, call3, ...)
val resultsByJob = jobs.zip(jobs.awaitAll())

val result1 = resultsByJob[call1]!!
```

Comment: Cool ! is there a way to identify each async operation instead of the results index ? like, not to be results[0] , I mean like results[call1]

Comment: Is there a way to map each async work to the type ?

Comment: If they have different types, I think the cleanest thing to do is keep separate variables and call await on them after declaring all of them. See edit.

Comment: You should also make sure you wrap all the `async` and `await`s in a `coroutineScope`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Is this so other `async` siblings don't have to run to completion if one of them fails? I'm not sure if that's always the desired behavior. Or is there some other benefit?

Comment: Yes, basically you'll have dangling async tasks executing in the background, the result of which you're no longer interested in. If you actually want to spawn background tasks, then you probably don't want to await on their completion in the first place. But even in that case it's pretty sure still want to act upon the fact that a task failed.